# I have Product Table and which has PRODUCTID Column which is Int I want all ProductID's in a single Row separated by comma

Tags: t-sql

I want all the product ID extracted from product table to single Row separated by a Comma . Each Product ID Separated by comma

PRODUCTID
6578,7657,65836,84947,8464..... SO ON

Comment: `SELECT STRING_AGG(PRODUCTID, ',') WITHIN  GROUP(ORDER BY PRODUCTID) FROM tab`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MS SQL Server you should be able to achieve your goal with the following code.

```
SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + CAST(PRODUCT_ID as VARCHAR(20))
            FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
```

---

With MSSQL Server 2017 and newer you could also use STRING_AGG().

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(PRODUCT_ID as VARCHAR(MAX)), ', ') FROM PRODUCT_TABLE
```